# assign elements in vector declared with new. C++

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to use a large 2D vector which I want to allocate with new (because it is large).

if I say:

```
vector< vector<int> > bob;
bob = vector< vector<int> >(16, vector<int>(1<<12,0));
bob[5][5] = 777;
```

it works. But if I say:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > *mary;
mary = new vector< vector<int> >(16, vector<int>(1<<12, 0));
mary[5][5] = 777;
```

it doesn't work and I get the error:

Error   1   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   c:\Users\jsparger\Documents\My Dropbox\ARI\VME_0.01\VME_0.01\V965.cpp   11  VME_0.01

Obviously I am new to C++. Could someone explain what syntax I need to use to perform this operation. mary is a pointer, so I can see why this wouldn't work, but *mary[5][5] = whatever is not allowed either because of "new", right?

Thanks for the help. This vector is what I will be using for now because it seems easy enough for my small c++ brain to understand, but feel free to let me know if a large vector like this is a bad idea, etc.

Thanks a bunch.

Edit:
I am mistaken about the "not allowed because of new". I don't know where I misread that, because it obviously works, and wouldn't make too much sense for it not to. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "*mary[5][5] = whatever is not allowed either because of "new""? Please clarify. You are probably mistaken here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `mary` is a pointer then you have to dereference it before applying the subscript operator:

```
(*mary)[5][5] = 777;
```

The parentheses are required because the subscript has higher precedence than the dereference.

Comment: Of course, [as FredOverflow points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256910/assign-elements-in-vector-declared-with-new-c/3256933#3256933), there aren't many times that it is useful to dynamically allocate a `vector`.

Comment: okay, thanks. For some reason I was under the impression that you couldn't do that if you allocated with new. (plus I was doing it wrong when I tried it anyway). Guess I seriously misread something somewhere. Thanks for the help on such a stupid question.

Answer (score 6):

Vectors store their elements on the heap, anyway. There's no point in allocating the vector object itself on the heap, since it is very small (typically 12 bytes on a 32-bit machine).

Comment: One valid reason to do this is to avoid needing to copy the base vector object when passing it between function calls.

Comment: @FredOverflow that will produce undefined behavior if you have a function which constructs a vector object as an automatic object and needs to return it to the caller.

Comment: @jMerliN: C++0x move semantics (rvalue references) fix that problem. http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html

Comment: @jMerliN: in that case, you can often return by value and rely on your compiler for copy elision: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @jMerliN hence my `std::swap` hint. `vector<T> t; foo().swap(t);` But better rely on copy elision, it's superior.

Answer (score 2):

In plain C, arrays and pointers are similar (not the same!), which leads to your confusion.  In plain C, if you have the following declarations:

```
int array1[100];
int *array2 = (int *)malloc(100*sizeof(int));
```

you can use array1 and array2 in exactly the same way.

However, if you write this in C:

```
int (*array3)[100];
```

This is something completely different.  Array3 is now a pointer to an array, not a pointer to the elements of the array anymore, and if you want to access an element, you have to write this:

```
(*array3)[5] = 123;
```

In C++, you are actually doing something similar, the second 'mary' is a pointer to the vector, not a pointer to the elements in the vector.  Therefore, you have to write this:

```
(*mary)[5][5] = 777;
```

Comment: Since when does C have vectors?

Comment: Since when is similar == same

Comment: Pointers and arrays in C are NOT the same, see "Expert C Programming."

Comment: @Fred, indeed, I should have written array instead of vector.  @Johannes, I compared the situation to plain C to explain why this error was made in C++.  No, it's not the same, it's similar.  I'll replace same by similar where appropriate.